# Prevent terraform from recreating pgp key

Tags: terraform, pgp

We are using S3 bucket for storing files with base64 PGP keys in them, then we reference those files with aws_s3_bucket_object and pass the value from file to aws_iam_access_key as pgp_key. That works fine but if any change is made (e.g. tags being changed) to the bucket where the PGP keys are stored, aws_iam_access_key is being recreated.

Is there a way to prevent this?

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "test_key" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.test_bucket.id
  key    = "pgp-keys/test_key.txt"
}

module "test_client" {
  source = "git::ssh://git@github.com/test-client"

  pgp_key              = data.aws_s3_bucket_object.test_key.body
  client_name          = "TestClient"
}
```

then inside "test_client" module the key is passed to aws_iam_access_key

```
resource "aws_iam_access_key" "client" {
  user    = aws_iam_user.client.name
  pgp_key = var.pgp_key
}
```

Terraform plan:

```
# data.aws_s3_bucket_object.test_key will be read during apply
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "test_client"  {
      + body                          = (known after apply)
      + bucket                        = "test-credential-recreation"
      + bucket_key_enabled            = (known after apply)
      + cache_control                 = (known after apply)
      + content_disposition           = (known after apply)
      + content_encoding              = (known after apply)
      + content_language              = (known after apply)
      + content_length                = (known after apply)
      + content_type                  = (known after apply)
      + etag                          = (known after apply)
      + expiration                    = (known after apply)
      + expires                       = (known after apply)
      + id                            = (known after apply)
      + key                           = "pgp-public-keys/test_key.txt"
      + last_modified                 = (known after apply)
      + metadata                      = (known after apply)
      + object_lock_legal_hold_status = (known after apply)
      + object_lock_mode              = (known after apply)
      + object_lock_retain_until_date = (known after apply)
      + server_side_encryption        = (known after apply)
      + sse_kms_key_id                = (known after apply)
      + storage_class                 = (known after apply)
      + tags                          = (known after apply)
      + version_id                    = (known after apply)
      + website_redirect_location     = (known after apply)
}

# aws_s3_bucket.test_client_setup_bucket will be updated in-place
~ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "test_client_setup_bucket" {
        acl                         = "private"
        arn                         = "arn:aws:s3:::test-credential-recreation"
        bucket                      = "test-credential-recreation"
        bucket_domain_name          = "test-credential-recreation.s3.amazonaws.com"
        bucket_regional_domain_name = "test-credential-recreation.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
        force_destroy               = false
        hosted_zone_id              = "Z21DNDUVLTQW6Q"
        id                          = "test-credential-recreation"
        region                      = "eu-central-1"
        request_payer               = "BucketOwner"
      ~ tags                        = {
          + "newtag" = "testchanges"
            "team"   = "test"
        }
}
```

Terraform apply:

```
module.test_client.aws_iam_access_key.client: Destroying...[id=AK......] 
module.test_client.aws_iam_access_key.client: Destruction complete after 1s 
data.aws_s3_bucket_object.test_key: Refreshing state...
module.test_client.aws_iam_access_key.client: Creating... 
module.test_client.aws_iam_access_key.client: Creation complete after 0s [id=AK...]
```

Comment: You can play around with [ignore_changes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes) for your `aws_iam_access_key`.

Comment: This question should actually say "Prevent Terraform from recreating aws_iam_access_key" as that is happening, bad formulation.

Comment: @Marcin thanks, I'll try that out

Comment: No problem. Let me know how it will go. If ignore_changes works, I can make an answer with extra info.

Comment: Can you share the plan output when this happens? You may want to do this with a throwaway PGP key because it would be useful to see the uncensored output that will likely be shown on the plan.

Comment: @Marcin ignore_changes worked when applied to s3 bucket where the PGP keys are stored! :) Did not work on the aws_iam_access_key resource, thanks again!

Comment: @ydaetskcoR sure, this is what happens: 


`module.test_client.aws_iam_access_key.client: Destroying... [id=AK......]
module.test_client.aws_iam_access_key.client: Destruction complete after 1s
data.aws_s3_bucket_object.test_key: Refreshing state...
module.test_client.aws_iam_access_key.client: Creating...
module.test_client.aws_iam_access_key.client: Creation complete after 0s [id=AK...]`
I guess it sees the aws_s3_bucket_object as new object and then tries to read the key from it again, but adding ignore_changes to s3 bucket as suggested by Marcin solved the problem in this case :)

Comment: Please edit the question to include the plan so you can format it and make it readable :)

Comment: Good point, but I do not have rights to edit the question :( as this is my first question asked. It is a new row with every `module.test` beginning, maybe that helps

Comment: You can always edit your own question? You get edit privileges to edit other people's questions and answers without them going into the edit queue at 2000 reputation but that doesn't apply to your own posts. Also your comment shows what happens when you apply it. I'd like to see the plan output which shows why things are changing.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Updated my question, thanks. The only change is new tag on the bucket.

Comment: The plan isn't showing what the apply is doing (destroying and recreating the `aws_iam_access_key` resource). Have you stripped that? It's important to show the whole context here. Ideally you'd edit your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces your issue where it keeps destroying your `aws_iam_access_key` resource on each apply.